# Add-ons to Log4Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I am currently dumping all my logging into Log4Net text files, and they are difficult to read. Is there a nice log4net processor (preferably a class I can add to my ASP.NET app, so that I can view logs remotely) that will lay out the log4net dump in a nice, easy to read and search format?

Comment: I've never heard of such thing for log4net, but it sounds like you're wanting something more along the lines of Elmah. http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Elah is great example, but it's really for catching and viewing exceptions, not generic log data.

Comment: Ahhhh I get what you mean now. Yeah can't say I've seen anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Apache tool for log4j called [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) which can apparently be used with log4net log files (instructions [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/07/15/46627.aspx)).

There is also a commercial tool called [Log4Net Dashboard](http://www.l4ndash.com) which can also do it.

Neither of these are web-based though.

There was a tool called log4xsl a while ago. If you configured log4net to output XML log files, you could apply the log4xsl XSLT stylesheet to render it nicely in a web browser. The project seems defunct though, but you could try to find it somewhere ([here](http://www.delarou.net/weblog/CategoryView,category,IStaySharp.aspx) may be a good starting point).

Comment: There is a developer snapshot of Chainsaw with a lot of bug fixes and new features available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy - you can configure it to use a VFSLogFilePatternReceiver to parse and tail regular text files..

Answer (score 2):

[Log2Console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/) can read log files, but you can also use it to monitor "live" events throught .Net Remoting or UDP Appenders. There is also a commercial tool "Log4View" that can to the same.

In your case logging to a database would make the most sense though. You can access it easily remotely and filtering is certainly no problem. Building a ASP.Net page with a data grid would be done very quickly so that you do not need to access the database directly.