# Free tools for reading log4net files from a remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

Are there any good free tools out there that can allow me to tail read a log4net log file when that file is generated on a production server?

I am thinking about adjusting it to push to the database and reading the database, but that seems overkill for something pretty simple. Am I missing an obvious tool?

Comment: Take look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702853/add-ons-to-log4net

Answer (score 1):

We tend to use the [log4net Remote Logging Service](http://log4netremotelogging.codeplex.com/) so that logs get pumped across the network rather than on the drive of a production server.

The service can then be configured to put logs into a file on the host machine.

Then, we use [log2console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/) to view the log file provided the log file is in a network share or you are working directly on the logging machine.

It's not clear exactly what your requirements are, but if you have access to the network share where the log file is, you might just be able to point log2console at it and view it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a [Chainsaw Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/howto/chainsaw.html) to your log4net configuration and then running [log2console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/) to receive/filter/parse the log as they're generated.